# Can Codeigniter Transaction Start When Another Transaction Running on The Same Table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I have model named demon_model that contain method like below:

```
class Hell_model extends CI_Model {
   function insert_demon_to_hell()
   {
       $this->db->trans_start();
       //insert to helldb for example
       //update to helldb for example
       $this->db->trans_complete();
   }
}
```

I have controller named demon_controller that like this

```
//REST CONTROLLER INCLUDED HERE

class Demon_controller extends REST_CONTROLLER {
    function contruct() {
        //LOAD HELL MODEL HERE
    }

    function demon () {
       $demon_id = $this->get('demon_id');
       $this->hell_model->insert_demon_to_hell($demon_id);
    }
}
```

This API will call when someone meet the demon. The question is when two or more person meet the demon (invoke the function) at the sametime will the query still run on the same table even though I already use transaction in the model function?.

Comment: If anything is ambiguous for you, fell free to comment below.

Comment: Transactions do not controll concurrency, they just ensure that all modifications are done or none of them. It is the locking mechanism that controls concurrency.

Comment: have you a solution for control the concurrency?

Comment: As I wrote: locks.

Comment: sorry for my bad description. because I dont know how to say that exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions do not controll concurrency, they just ensure that all modifications are done or none of them. It is the [locking mechanism](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-transaction-model.html) that controls concurrency.

Therefore the number of transactions running at the same time is theoretically unlimited. However, what and when they can do is restricted by the locks implicitly or explicitly set by the statements within the transactions.

One more important thing: `db->trans_start()` starts a **database** transaction, not a CI transaction. This means that the transaction applies to the changes done on the db level only, not on changes done on CI level. E.g. if you make a change to a property to a CI object that is not persisted in the database, then a rollback will not affect the value of that property.